# Create Checkbox in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to create the checkbox inside the jqgrid columns and using the below code

```
{ 
   name: 'CanDo', width: 50, index: 'CanDo', 
   edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, 
   formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: true} 
}
```

Json object is returning either "True" or "False"

But the check box itself is not created in grid. What would be the issue?

Please help.

Edit: Using jquery.jqGrid.BasicOnly.min.js 4.1.2

```
$("#pGrid").jqGrid({
            datastr: '@Html.Raw(@Model.PList)',
            datatype: 'jsonstring',
            colNames: ['id','CanDo' ,'Name'],
                colModel: [
                        { name: 'id', hidden: true },
                        { name: 'CanDo', width: 50, index: 'CanDo',editable: true,  edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: true},
                        { name: 'Name', width: 150 }                        
                      ],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 100,
            height: "200",
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: '<span class="spanH2">Test Process</span>'
        });
```

**JSON**

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":2,
 "rows": [
   {"id":"1","cell":["1","True","Callback"]},
   {"id":"8","cell":["8","False","Complaint"]}]}
```

Comment: Did you try setting as `editoptions: { value: "true:false" }`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you are missing the `editable:true` option. Try this:

```
{ 
 name: 'CanDo', width: 50, index: 'CanDo', 
 editable: true,
 edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, 
 formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: true} 
}
```

Comment: Now I added that option as well. Still the issue is not resolved.

Comment: Hmm... not sure what to tell you. I think you need to post a larger example with your full jqGrid code, the XML/JSON response from the server, and a description/picture of what actually *is* displaying in your grid.

Comment: I just verified the html created for that specific grid cells. It has <td title="False" role="gridcell" aria-describedby="pGrid_CanDo">

Comment: What does the grid cell contain?

Comment: I am using "jquery.jqGrid.BasicOnly.min.js". Does this has any limitations?

Comment: I do not see the closing </ td>.

Comment: @Gansun: Should be something like: <td role="gridcell" title="" aria-describedby="pGrid_CanDo"><input type="checkbox" value="&nbsp;" offval="no"></td>

Comment: @Gansun - Most likely. You need to include the code for editing. I suggest downloading the entire jqGrid 4.1.2 code to see if it fixes your problem. If it does, then you can selectively remove components you do not need.