# Is it Possible to populate Controls in JqGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I wanted to implement `JqGrid` in my Project.

But, here my requirement is that i need to display controls in the grid.

For example, i have a column that can take values either true or false.

But, i would like to represent this in the form of checkbox checked and unchecked format.

So, i wanted to know whether this is possible or not by using JqGrid. Please help.

Comment: Please check Oleg answer for jQgrid related questions. He always rocks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it with `formatter` in a column model

```
{
name: 'MyCol', index: 'MyCol', editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', 
editoptions: { value:"True:False"},formatter: "checkbox"
}
```

or you can specify a custom fortmatter to render the column

```
formatter: checkboxColumnRenderer
```

then

```
function checkboxColumnRenderer(cellValue, opts, rowObject){
   return "checkbox-html";
}
```

Check [jqGrid with an editable checkbox column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928919/jqgrid-with-an-editable-checkbox-column) and [Create Checkbox in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915263/create-checkbox-in-jqgrid) and

Comment: can we bind drop downs as well?

Comment: @Avinash, you bind dropdown as well. It just another columnRenderer or a formatter with different format options

Comment: OK..Thanks..I will try it..can we do the same using Jquery datatables..i am asking these things because if am confused to choose between the plugin to use in the application

Comment: @Avinash, as long as I know jQgrid got all the possiblities, also we will get more help here for jQGrid, especially from Oleg :) I recommand you jQGrid FMHO

Answer (score 3):

jqGrid supports many [predefined formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) which include `formatter: "checkbox"`. It displays disabled (the user can't check/uncheck the checkboxs) checkboxs. You can use `true`, `false` or `1`, `0` as the input values for the `formatter: "checkbox"`.

One can use [custom formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) additionally in the cases when you don't find predefined formatters which full correspond your requirements, but in case of usage checkboxs the standard `formatter: "checkbox"` should be OK.